# How to use activecell.formula in for loop VBA

Tags: vba

In a for loop, I need to refer to the loop id `j` in a formula like the following sample (`R1C[j-36]`). However, this results in errors when the code is run. How to fix this, please?

```
For j = 1 To 3

                Range("SRinclSpread").Select
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],sheet1!R4C1:R54C34,R1C[j-36],0)+R13C[4]"
Next j
```

Comment: Is the range `"SRinclSpread"` a single cell?  If so (and even if not), why are you assigning 3 different formulas to it?  Why not just assign the last of those 3 formulas to the cell(s) and save time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split your formula in two strings, combine with &, and use j as a variable between the strings

```
For j = 1 To 3
Range("SRinclSpread").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],sheet1!R4C1:R54C34,R1C[" & j -36 & "],0)+R13C[4]"
Next j
```

Edit: Updated including @YowE3K suggestion

Comment: Could you explaine your syntax a bit, please? What if I need to use j only? Can I write " & j & " to replace R1C[" & j -36 & "]?

Comment: Yes, you can! In the line: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],sheet1!R4C1:R54C34,R1C[" & j -36 & "],0)+R13C[4]"`, you are assigning the formula in the Active cell a value according to the string on the right-hand side of the "equal-sign" (operator).
Strings and variables can be combined using `&` to make one common string which is then assigned according to the operator.
E.g.: if `j` has the value "37", then the string becomes `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],sheet1!R4C1:R54C34,R1C[" & 37 -36 & "],0)+R13C[4]"`which combines to `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],sheet1!R4C1:R54C34,R1C[1],0)+R13C[4]"`